# What are best practices for tracing the flow of a large rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mixins, monkeypatching

If you are a new developer to a large (very large!) rails app it can be really difficult to trace through the flow of what is calling what, where a method is defined, and how to 'grok' how the whole thing works.

What are best practices for how to find information like:

I'm in class Foo and it calls a method bar but there is no def bar in the file.  It must be mixed in or a concern or monkey patched etc. in somehow.  What are steps 1, 2, 3 for where to look?  I don't see anything obvious at the top of the file and greping for 'def bar' doesn't return anything.

Comment: Similar question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630862/how-do-i-find-where-a-ruby-method-is-declared

Comment: Also, foo.method(:bar).owner might be useful. And consider that it may be a dynamic method in which case grepping may not be helpful.

Comment: Based on your karma, I imagine you've already discovered pry, which is really really helpful for tracing. I'm putting this up for others who might stumble upon this question. Let me know if you want a longer answer.

Answer (score 0):

Metaprogramming! Probably defined the methods on the fly based on the params passed. Ex. [define_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-define_method)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
grep "def bar" app/* lib/* -irn (optionally -l)
```

If I'm in the file open, I most likely would use [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html), because I use vim, but if you are using an IDE it might help you somehow to find this method.

Or yet, I could simply use [the debugger](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-ruby-debug), where you can inspect your objects in runtime.