# How to find to which module(s) a method (parameterize) belongs to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My goal is to add a new method `parameterize_cs` (parameterize case sensitive, that doesn't perform `downcase` on the resulting string).

For this I need to find to which `Module` `parameterize` belongs to, or where it is located, so I can extend that with my new function.

But I'm stuck at finding out where `parameterize` is located.

I tryed using `Method#source_location`, but that fails because calling `method(:parameterize)` in rails console returned: `NameError: undefined method 'parameterize' for class Object'`

Any ideas where to go from here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one way, is to look at the Rails documentation. Searching for `parameterize` you can see it is defined [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize).

You can also find it in the console using `source_location` by instantiating a string.

```
''.method(:parameterize).source_location
```

[How do I find where a ruby method is declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630862/how-do-i-find-where-a-ruby-method-is-declared) has more details.